# Select div if it has both classes - valid CSS?

Tags: css, standards

In firefox the following CSS is only applied to the last div, as its the only div with both classes:

```
.a.b {
color: red;
}

<div class="a"> Stuff A</div>
<div class="b"> Stuff B</div>
<div class="a b"> Stuff A and B</div>
```

Is this valid CSS? Im just worried as ive never heard of it before.
Thanks

Comment: Just so I am sure I understand correctly, the fact that the style is only applied when the div have both classes is the result you wanted, but you want to know if it is a valid way to do it, or just a glitch in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid css. Almost all browsers support multiple class selector except ie6

```
Browser support s
Mac: Safari 4.0 supported
Mac: Chrome 5.0 supported
Mac: FireFox 3.6    supported
Mac: Opera 10   supported
Win: FireFox 3.6    supported
Win: Opera 10   supported
Win: IE6    NOT SUPPORTED
Win: IE7    supported
Win: IE8    supported
```

Source:
http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/multiple-classes/

Comment: "only if the orders are same"? The order is not taken into consideration at all. Classes are effectively done as a set, not an ordered list.

Comment: I can't in good conscience upvote this until you get rid of the bit about order which is just wrong...